# SwiftUI: How to know correct order of modifiers?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, vstack

I'm pretty new to **SwiftUI**, learning it for the first time, and couldn’t understand why the below snippet doesn’t work. Ideally, the **VStack** should stretch in all directions and the **Image** should have a width of 200px without losing its aspect ratio.

#### Code

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            Image("Image Name")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 200)
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        }
        .background(Color.red)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
```

After I **accidentally reordered the modifiers**, it worked. So, how am I supposed to know the correct order of modifiers without a hit and trial method each time?

```
// new VStack modifier order 
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
.background(Color.red)

// new Image modifier order
.resizable()
.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
.frame(width: 200)
```

Comment: what you mean with **recording modifier** can you show how you recored?

Answer (score 9):

The best way to think about it for now is to imagine that SwiftUI renders your view after *every* single modifier. So, as soon as you say `.background(Color.red)` it colors the background in red, regardless of what frame you give it. If you then later expand the frame, it won’t magically redraw the background – that was already applied.

Of course, this isn’t actually how SwiftUI works, because if it did it would be a performance nightmare, but it’s a neat mental shortcut to use while you’re learning.

Please refer [to this link](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/why-modifier-order-matters#:%7E:text=Every%20time%20we%20modify%20a,up%3A%20ModifiedContent%3CModifiedContent%3C%E2%80%A6) for more details.